# What does "school closure policy" mean?

Tags: meaning

I saw a sentence as below

> With the cross-country context, Cronert (2020) investigated 167
> countries worldwide on their reactions to the Covid-19 pandemic,
> focusing on the political determinant of **school closure policy**.

I am wondering what is the "**school closure policy**" in this context?

Comment: Can you explain what is unclear. . . it is a "policy" for deciding on "school closure"

Comment: @JamesK I faced this phrase and I did not fully understand it even googling. And because it is a policy so I should not guess. That is why I am asking here. Astralbee also has a quite comprehensive answer here then.

Comment: Excellent question.  I am a native speaker familiar with the subject.  And, yet, I find the sentence difficult. It should have been 2 sentences at the very least.  Hopefully, the stand alone "with the cross-country context" phrase refers to a previous sentence in the article. As best as I can tell a researcher named Cronert investigated the school closure policies for 167 countries, focused on the politics that determined policy for each country, and wrote a paper in 2020?  Not sure why the OP Question is closed.  Both native and non-native speakers might struggle with this sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is quite literal - it is **a policy that outlines when an individual school (or all schools) should be closed**. The policy might outline specific trigger events that would mean certain steps had to be taken.

During the 2020 pandemic, all UK schools were ordered to close for a time, but when they were reopened each school (or education authority) had to act individually to determine if and when a school should close in the event of localised outbreaks. So there could be national and local policies, but the context of your example seems to refer to a national, governmental policy.